# My manager wants me transfer to another location that I am not comfortable with

Tags: management, communication, human-resources, manager

I am currently working in a place that is near my home. My manager wants me to transfer to some other place that I don't want to go (family reasons).

How can I tell him politely that I don't want to, so that I can continue to work in the same place, without being rude?

Comment: you can simply say "Sir,am not comfortable to work "that place" because "your reason", it my humble request to cancel my transfer order"

Comment: Reason is my family problem.But manager is not accecpting that.he kind of forcing me to go there.what are the other reason to say??

Comment: There may not be a lot else you *can* say in general. You could ask your HR people or check your staff handbook to see if your company has a formal mechanism for saying no to these kinds of transfers.

Comment: Also, was there anything in agreements you signed when you took the job?

Comment: yes.As per policy, I can't deny that.But is there any reason that is acceptable in most of the situations like this.

Comment: Parental care is a legally backed reason in India.

Comment: You might have to accept that if you want to keep your job you might not have a choice in the matter.

Comment: Depends so much on what sort of contract you have and what grade you are and the legal system in your country

Comment: @dude Grovelling like that is never a good idea

Answer (score 14):

> How can I say him politely so that I can continue to work in same
>   place without being rude?

Depending on the nature of the business, and your role in it, this can be difficult.

In some companies, refusing a transfer might mean your career would be blocked and you couldn't get promoted. In some companies, refusing a transfer might even get you dismissed.

Many years (and several careers) ago, I worked for a supermarket chain. The only way to get ahead was to accept that you would be transferred every so often. Refusing a transfer usually meant that you would never get promoted.

As you have indicated in your situation, I knew that going in and so it wasn't a surprise when I was transferred. It was just a standard part of the job.

You should have a conversation with your manager to find out what your options are in this case. **Simply tell him that you'd really rather stay in your current location and why.**

Ask about the company policy regarding transfers. Ask about your options in this particular case. Discuss what are the ramifications of staying in place - then make your decision based on a more complete understanding.

If you are in a union, you should talk with your union rep and discuss your contractual rights.

Comment: In some states if they let you go for not taking a transfer it is called constructive discharge and they would be liable.. check your states employment laws for constructive discharge

Comment: @erik - I would hope there are specific guidelines surrounding those laws, its not a matter of simply refusing a transfer, it has to meet certain guidelines.  because simply refusing a transfer without an actual reason seems like a good reason to get rid of you.

Comment: In California, the California Supreme Court defines constructive discharge as follows:"In order to establish a constructive discharge, an employee must plead and prove, by the usual preponderance of the evidence standard, that the employer either intentionally created or knowingly permitted working conditions that were so intolerable or aggravated at the time of the employee's resignation that a reasonable employer would realize that a reasonable person in the employee's position would be compelled to resign." 

.

Comment: I'm not sure a somewhat longer commute is sufficient to prove "conditions so intolerable or aggravated" as to force the person's resignation.

Comment: @PurpleVermont If we assume the OP is a reasonable person, and this transfer is compelling him to resign, then that would meet the letter of the law. The difficult part would be proving those assumptions in court.

Comment: @RedAlert - in any case I don't see the OP stating that he would resign rather than accept the transfer, just that he doesn't want to transfer because the new location is less convenient for him.

Comment: Presumably if the transfer were to another state/province/country and the employee were essentially being forced to relocate, it could qualify as constructive dismissal. A longer commute time is not "intolerable" in the context of the "reasonable person" test - unless the distance was actually specified in the employment contract.

Comment: @Ramhound I think it varies from country to country. In Israel a relocation of over 40 KM from where you live, means that if you decline the relocation you have the rights of a person who was fired by the company. Meaning a request for a re-location needs to be reasonable in the distance.

Comment: Hence the "reasonable" if something violates a law it isn't reasonable